# change the name of file instead of SaveFileDialog.OverwritePrompt

Tags: c#, winforms

in my windows form app user can add image in a folder in hard drive with saveFileDialog.
How can I change the name of image instead of OverwritePrompt alert with adding a variable integer to the name of image?

Comment: Your question isn't completely clear - are you asking how you would automatically change the name (by adding a number) if the user tries to overwrite an existing file?

Comment: exactly .so I think it was clear

Comment: I'd look at handling the `FileOK` event (when the user clicks the OK button).  You can check to see if that file already exists and then rename the file.

Comment: Could you help me more? what do I write in FileOk event?

Comment: I can try - I don't do a lot of WinForms development.  Give me a few minutes to test my idea - I'm not 100% sure that it will work - depends on when/how the save actually happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement a check of the file name just before saving :

```
int i = 1;
while(File.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
                                + "\" + saveFileDialog.FileName)
{
    saveFileDialog.FileName = saveFileDialog.FileName + "_" + i;
    i++;
}
```

This needs to go just before opening the stream to write the file:

```
System.IO.FileStream fs = (System.IO.FileStream)saveFileDialog.OpenFile();
// Write to your file
fs.Close();
```